# Diagonal difference on HackerRank

Tags: c, algorithm

I was trying to solve [this](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/diagonal-difference/problem). My algorithm gives right answer in ofline compiler. I dont know where is the error. I am completely new to C language.

The problem asked to create a function to find the absolute difference of right and left diagonals of a square matrix.

This is my solution for the website. When I run the code online it gives the output 12.

```
int diagonalDifference(int arr_rows, int arr_columns, int** arr) {

    int primary_sum, secondary_sum = 0;
    for(int row,column = 0; row < arr_rows && column < arr_columns; row++, column++){

        primary_sum += arr[row][column];
        secondary_sum += arr[row][arr_columns - column - 1];

    }

    return abs(primary_sum - secondary_sum);

}
```

I wrote a similar program to test ofline.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void matrix_sum(int arr_rows, int arr_columns, int arr[3][3]);
int main(void){

    int arr[3][3] = {
                    {11, 2, 4},
                    {4, 5, 6},
                    {10, 8, -12}
                  };

    matrix_sum(3, 3, arr);


}


void matrix_sum(int arr_rows, int arr_columns, int arr[3][3]){

    int row,column = 0;
    int primary_sum, secondary_sum = 0;
    int digonals[3];
    int s_digonals[3];

    for(; row < arr_rows && column < arr_columns; row++, column++){
        primary_sum += arr[row][column];
        secondary_sum += arr[row][arr_columns - column - 1];

        digonals[row] = arr[row][column];
        s_digonals[row] = arr[row][arr_columns - column - 1];

    }

    printf("primary_sum = %i\n", primary_sum);
    printf("secondary_sum = %i\n", secondary_sum);

    for(int i = 0; i < row; i++){
        printf("%i ",digonals[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    for(int i = 0; i < row; i++){
        printf("%i ",s_digonals[i]);
    }
    printf("\n%i\n", abs(primary_sum - secondary_sum) );



}
```

second program gives correct result which is 15 and I don't know why online compiler gives output 12.

Input was.

3

11 2 4

4 5 6

10 8 -12

Comment: So the code gives the right answer, and you wonder where the *error* is? Why do you think there's any "error" in your code?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude website is not accepting my solution.

Comment: Because you ran out of time, right?

Comment: And please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/), and all of http://idownvotedbecau.se/ to learn some reasons your question might be down-voted. Finally, please [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: @Yunnosch wrong answer.

Comment: So you think the result is the correct answer but the judge disagrees?

Comment: Without knowing the exact input you get, it's hard to impossible to properly debug your program. That's why such sites and the questions they cause posted here are so despised. They also don't really teach you anything useful, only how to be good at such sites, which really doesn't translate well into real-life experience.

Comment: Initializing `primary_sum` should help.

Comment: I'm surprised it ran at all, without a memory error. Take a look at `int row,column = 0` in combination with the ggloren's answer. You got lucky (Or rather, for debugging, unlucky) that it worked on your own machine. May I also suggest, not having row/column as different variables (They are always equal anyway)

Comment: As mentioned by others, your local variable initializations doesn't work as you apparently seem to think. For example `int row, column = 0;` initializes `column` to zero, but doesn't initialize `row`. It is equal to `int row; int column = 0;`. Uninitialized local variables will haven an *indeterminate* value, that can seem almost random.

Comment: " I am completely new to C language." - So if you don't know the language you instantly go to the parliament of a foreign country and hold a public speech? How about learning the lenguage before you join some programming contest?

Comment: @toohonestforthissite I was just applying the knowledge I learned from random youtube videos. This was a beginners problem and not some competition. I only learned something new by asking the question. Please don't be rude next time.

Comment: "I was just applying the knowledge I learned from random youtube videos" - That's exactly the problem! You cannot learn C from obscure YT videos or online "tutorials" or trial&error! Get a textbook!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic seems correct. But have a look at this line:

```
 int primary_sum, secondary_sum = 0;
```

What is `primary_sum` initialized to--`0` or a garbage value? HackerRank offers a box called "your output", which shows your sum as `18179734`. I'll let you debug from here.